# Unrecognized alter operation in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create partitions on table `posts` so in the first partition (column `status`) are values `public`, `admin`, `moder` and `rec`.

In the second partition (column `status`) is one single value - `archive`

In phpmyadmin:

```
ALTER TABLE posts
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS (status) (
PARTITION P1 VALUES IN ('public', 'admin', 'moder', 'rec'),
PARTITION P2 VALUES IN ('archive')
);
```

red x error:

> unrecognized alter operation. near`;`)

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You syntax is fine and the red X error message is cosmetic only (most likely a bug in phpMyAdmin's SQL parser). Submit the code and it will work. Reported in https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13595.

Comment: means that no way to run our query?

Comment: Even though phpMyAdmin's parser reports an error, you should be able to run the query.